# How to insert images from image paths stored in a dataframe, into shiny report in r

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny report from a dataframe that produces reports about performance for individual people regarding procedures they have done. At each procedure, pictures are taken Each row of the dataframe is a procedure with the pathnames of the images taken as follows:

```
DatePRocedurePerformed   ReportFromProcedure ImagesFromProcedure
12/12/2014                blblabalbabl        Myfolder/img1.jpeg,Myfolder/img2.Myfolder/jpeg,Myfolder/img9.jpeg
13/11/2015                sdfsdfsdf           Myfolder/Myimage3.jpeg,Myfolder/AnotherImage.jpeg
01/02/2015                gdgdgdgdf           Myfolder/Stuff.jpeg,Myfolder/MoreStuff.jpeg
```

I would like to produce a word document (using shiny) that displays a simple table taken from the above dataframe.

The shiny report is simply a pander table taken directly from the dataframe

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
pander(Alltbl,justify='left',split.table=Inf,caption="Table 4")
```
````

I want to insert the actual images from the filenames given into the table rather than the pathname. The images are stored on a local directory.
Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: Maybe `renderImage` ? (not sure to understand what you're doing).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I have altered the question to better explain but essentially I would like to produce a word document which has a table in it. This table is from a dataframe. One of the dataframe columns contains the pathname of images so that when the table is rendered in the word document, the images are displayed (rather than the pathname)